# How can I allow only one instance of app to run which created in APP DESIGNER of MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, matlab-app-designer

I created application in app designer of matlab and install it in apps. 
I can run one or more instance this apps but I need only one. For example in "GUIDE" of matlab is option: "GUI allows only one instance to run (singleton)"

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You might be interested in knowing that there's [ru.SO].

Answer (score 0):

If you check the code GUIDE generates you will find out that it uses global application data for keeping count of application instances. So you could implement something similar with `setappdata(0, ...)` and `getappdata(0, ...)`.